# How to find sum of values of objects in array in dart?

Tags: arrays, dart

I have an array that is like following:

```
[{name: Cibo, quantity: 3}, 
{name: Cibo, quantity: 2}, 
{name: Invia Regalo, quantity: 3}, 
{name: Invia Regalo, quantity: 1}]
```

How can I find the total quantity for these objects by combining the same names?

So output would look like:

```
[
{name: Invia Regalo, quantity: 4},
{name: Cibo, quantity: 5},
]
```

I have tried something like this, but does not work in Dart.

```
var categoryTotal = [];

    category.forEach((category) {
      print(category);
      var categ =
          categoryTotal.firstWhere((cat) => cat['name'] == category['name']);
      print("Category is $categ");
      if (categ != null) {
        categ['quantity'] += category['quantity'];
      } else {
        categoryTotal.add(category);
      }
    });
    print(categoryTotal);
```

Answer (score 1):

I will in general not recommend the use of maps maps to handle objects that contains different types of values. Instead, use classes. It makes it a lot easier to write type safe code.

Also, I will not recommend using the `.forEach()` method when you have multiple lines of code since it can make it difficult to read. Instead, use a for-each loop.

I have made the following solution to handle your list of maps. The `sumMap` is for making the code more efficient by using a `Map` to handle the sums of `quantity`. The result are then created based on `sumMap`:

```
void main() {
  final array = [
    {'name': 'Cibo', 'quantity': 3},
    {'name': 'Cibo', 'quantity': 2},
    {'name': 'Invia Regalo', 'quantity': 3},
    {'name': 'Invia Regalo', 'quantity': 1},
  ];

  final sumMap = <String, int>{};
  for (final map in array) {
    sumMap.update(
      map['name']! as String,
      (sum) => sum + (map['quantity']! as int),
      ifAbsent: () => map['quantity']! as int,
    );
  }

  final result = [
    for (final entry in sumMap.entries)
      {'name': entry.key, 'quantity': entry.value}
  ];

  print(result);
  // [{name: Cibo, quantity: 5}, {name: Invia Regalo, quantity: 4}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `orElse: () => null` to avoid exeption. So, final code would look like this:

```
var categoryTotal = [];

    category.forEach((category) {
      var categ = categoryTotal.firstWhere(
        (cat) => cat['name'] == category['name'],
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      if (categ != null) {
        categ['quantity'] += category['quantity'];
      } else {
        categoryTotal.add(category);
      }
    });
    print(categoryTotal);
```